# How do I get the color temperature value of Night Light?

Tags: night-light

How can I get the color temperature value that my Night light has set?

Comment: Ubuntu flavor and version?

Comment: @Levente Night Light is a GNOME feature, so the OP probably uses GNOME.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the value it's set on currently, run this command in the terminal:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-temperature
```

To set it to a specific kelvin value yourself use this example:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-temperature 5900
```

---

If you want to deal with this on a graphical interface, install the dconf-editor app:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

It may take a little time to get the hang of using its navigation feature.

You need to get to the `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color` namespace. Or you can use its search feature to look for "night-light".

Answer (score 0):

Here the whole command to enable night-light:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled true
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-temperature 4700
```